# How to handle drag and drop lists in mongodb/express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js, mongoose

I'm building a kanban board like spa with user boards that contain lists, and lists that contain cards all with drag and drop functionality using vue.js in front-end and express.js with mongoose in back-end.

I'm currently stuck on how to set up my models and sorting correctly.

Could anyone give me an example of a 3 simple mongoose models for a board, a list and a card that would work for a drag and drop functionality for lists and cards, together with sorting, routes would be awesome too?

I'm completely lost if I should use embedding or referencing, I've tried both ways but it doesn't seem right.

EDIT:

I know how trello/wakan/kanbanflow does it, I know about the websockets way, but for now I just need a very simple, basic set-up without realtime updates.

From what I gather -

Board model - contains members array with id's of users
List model - contains board id and list of cards (refs or embedded?), or just board id?
Card model - contains board id and list id?

How would I query the cards for the board view, as they have to be in their own respected lists?

I get a board by id, then use aggregation and lookup/fill boards lists, then for each of those lists i should look up/fill with cards? Sounds like a lot of querying going on, not really efficient?

For board I only really need to add members, change the title.

For list - I need to be able to re-order them and change title.

For cards - Alot of stuff going on here: title, description, card members, activities, comments etc.. I think I'll use referenced activities,comments, card members etc, but my main concern is how to handle the re-ordering and creating/deleting cards/lists with drag and drop?

https://codesandbox.io/s/jv4mj9vl33

Here's an example app sandbox to get a better understanding of what functionality i want to achieve. This is where I am so far. With this logic, I have 3 collections - boards lists and cards and earch are refereced to its parent by id.

Comment: Try to define your problem better.  Show what you've tried and and why it didn't work for your situation.  As it is, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with what you're doing.

Comment: It kinda sounds like you want us to do your work for you. Which isn't really the purpose of Stack Overflow. I'd suggest reading the [help] to learn more about the guidelines of the site. It also has a lot of tips about how to write good questions. @Paul is correct when he says to define the problem better. What have you tried so far? What specifically is not working? It's hard to easily pin point what your exact question is. `Give me an example` isn't really a question.

Comment: Also, how does this relate to [tag:vue.js]?

Comment: I've stated that I've tried numerous things both embedding and referencing, gave a codepen example of a vue application with the desired specs, what the hell more do You guys need? My question is how to design for such functionality, I'm not asking to do my work.

Comment: @KarolisStakėnas Programming design questions are considered off topic on this site. As I’ve said, I highly encourage you to read the [help]. It gives a lot of great information about the guidelines of the site. It’s even linked in the close notice above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision for embedding vs referencing is often influenced by the way you want to query a data. 
It is also an interesting question if cards would also contain discussions. (<- but that is another discussion) because it would bring another nesting level.

What about

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({bucket:'string', position:'number', title: 'string', body: 'string',isDone:'boolean'});
var card = mongoose.model('Card', schema);
```

the board would be all cards grouped by bucket and ordered by position within the bucket. (For Grouping it is recommended to use the aggregate function).

Dragging within a bucket (changing) the position would be to update the positions of the cards. Moving the cards between buckets would be to update the bucket field.

When you look at trello I think they worked with websockets which pushes changes to the clients and the client reacts to the updates.

This would mean a total different model. So, the server contains all changes for a board. So you would need to model all changes as commands/events. "CARD_CREATED", CARD_MOVED_TO_BUCKET with its corresponding payload. With this, you would be able to push changes to the server and back to the client. You want to look at eventsourcing, cqrs, redux, to get more information about storing the state as a series of changes. Think about your bank account. The total is an aggregated result of all debits and credits.

So while the first approach will work for you, the second one could be interesting to look into it.